# How to import data from mySQL to MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, meteor, database

How to import data from mysql to mongoDB? I have a mysql database which updates once in a day. I need to import or read **some data** from it and show it to my web site. I am developing my web site in Meteor JS framework, which uses only mongoDB. What is the best solution for this problem? I think it will be better reading data from mysql and write it to mongoDB instantly. I cant use database migration its because my mqsql data base updates everyday. Any tools or programming example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Meteor is based on Node.js, you can use a Node.js MySQL driver from NPM: https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=mysql
With this, you should be able to read the data from MySQL and push it into your MongoDB.